# Не верно определяется язык при ajax запросе Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

У меня на сайте, который написал на yii2, есть мультиязычность. Все работает хорошо, но когда я делаю ajax запрос на метод контроллера, который возвращает, например, фразу "Спасибо, запрос отправлен", она не переводится на нужный язык. Это можно как то побороть?

Comment: Бороть не надо, нужно разобраться в самом методе и как он делает перевод, а после этого воспроизвести такой запрос в AJAX.

Comment: спасибо, я понял в чем ошибка. у меня язык оприделяется через url, а когда делаю ajax - url без префикса языка